# Problem with meta key on Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, xkb

I have a problem with meta key in Emacs. I trying to use M-> or M-< but in fedora meta key is left Alt that is key change layout (alt+shift) when i press M->(alt+shift+>). How people solve this problem? (Conflict key problem)

Answer (score 3):

Well, considering the minimal information provided, it sounds like you should go into keyboard shortcut settings in Fedora and change the key combo to change layout to some other combo like `Ctrl+Alt`.

Comment: yes it's conflict key problem but i want to know how emacs user solve this problem changes layout key or other solution.